# HTML - Pattern to validate nomenclature

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to use the "pattern" attribute for HTML5 but I do not have much experience in the regex.

The nomenclature that I wish to validate is the following:

```
0100455_LM_Izaguirre
```

Where "0100455" will generally have 7 to 10 characters, "LM" may vary "LM, LI, AQ" and everything that comes after (eg "Izaguirre") is a text with at least 1 character.
What is important is that scripts are maintained and needed.

All this is necessary to validate a value that will then be modified in PHP and will later be pasted into a Word with PHPWord.

```
//0100455_LM_Izaguirre
$sitebase = "0100455_LM_Izaguirre";
$string = explode("_", $sitebase);
$idcontrol = $string[1].'_'.$string[0];
```

Comment: Should this be handled in javascript (client-side) or PHP (server-side)?

Comment: It is for PHP. Its worked fine ^[0-9]{7,10}_[A-Z]{2}_[A-Za-z\s]+$

Comment: You could also consider using character classes - e.g. \d instead of 0-9, \w instead of A-Z unless _a-z_ and `_` would not be acceptable in those sections - refer to [this cheat sheet](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse190m/12sp/cheat-sheets/php-regex-cheat-sheet.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[0-9]{7,10}_[A-Z]{2}_[A-Za-z]+$` will be the regex pattern if `LM` will be any 2 charecters.

`^[0-9]{7,10}_(LM|LI|AQ)_[A-Za-z]+$` will be the regex pattern if `LM` will only be {LM, LI, AQ}.

**Demo:-**

```js
var rx = /^[0-9]{7,10}_(LM|LI|AQ)_[A-Za-z]+$/gm;
console.log("0100455_LM_Izaguirre".match(rx));
console.log("0100455_YM_Izaguirre".match(rx));
console.log("0100455_AQ_Izaguirre".match(rx));
```

> null will return for no matches